# Using Splittext from GSAP in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, gsap

I am very new to GSAP and Vue.js. I am actually using it for the first time.
I am trying to do a text animation with Splittext from GSAP.
This is what I did but I am getting this error : *gsap__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.SplitText is not a constructor*.
I really don't understand where this come from.

```js
<script>
import gsap from 'gsap'
import {TimelineLite, SplitText} from 'gsap';


export default {

    mounted(){
        this.textReveal()
    },

    methods : {
        textReveal(){
            var $text = document.querySelector(".splittext"),
            mySplitText = new SplitText($text, {type:"words"}),
            splitTextTimeline = gsap.timeline();
            gsap.set($text, {perspective:400});
            mySplitText.split({type:"chars, words"});
            splitTextTimeline.from(mySplitText.chars, {duration: 0.5, scale:2, autoAlpha:0,  transformOrigin:"100% 50%", ease: "back.out", stagger: 0.02});
            splitTextTimeline.play();
            
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
    <div class="help-page">
        <img class="close" src="@/assets/icons/close.svg" alt="">
        <div class="text-container">
            <h1>What to see</h1>
            <p class="splittext">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum, quos, magnam omnis perferendis laboriosam voluptatibus aperiam eligendi rerum fugit esse, ipsum vero quis reiciendis accusantium totam soluta ad. Quia tempore aliquam dolore eligendi amet, id quae sed tempora minus dignissimos deserunt corporis debitis error delectus dicta quidem, alias eaque!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: [Same post on GreenSock's forums](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/26534-using-splittext-with-vuejs/) for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Splittext is apparently not free and that is why I can't use it ...

Comment: That's correct. For the reasoning behind _why_ GSAP has some products that are paid, see [this post](https://greensock.com/why-license/).

Comment: Found an incredibly [simple alternative](https://www.spltjs.com), it's even open source!